# Write dataframes from a list into multiple excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I have :

```
list_of_DataFrames = [df_1, df_2, df_n, ...]
```

I would like to write each of these dataframes into a distinct excel file.

I tried :

```
list_of_DataFrames.to_excel("pathTo/ExcelFile.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list doesn't have a `to_excel` method. The only way you can do is by looping over the list.

```
for i in range(len(list_of_DataFrames)):
    list_of_DataFrames[i].to_excel("pathTo/ExcelFile-{}.xlsx".format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i, df in enumerate([df_1, df_2, df_n, ...]):
    df.to_excel(f"pathTo/ExcelFile_{i}.xlsx")
```